# Android Studio Gradle errors after updating to 9.4.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, google-play-services, build.gradle

After updating to the new Firebase version, I'm getting the following errors. I've been searching around, and apparently I have to remove some jar files, but I can't seem to understand where to remove these files that are causing conflicts.

**The errors are as follows.**

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzml;

Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmm;

Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmn;

Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmo;

Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmp;

Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmq;

Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzmr;

Error:7 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

**Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    ///firebase////
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'

    //# Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    //compile 'io.github.rockerhieu:emojicon:1.4.1'

    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Here's the Project Gradle.**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Show us your gradle file, thanks

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez please see the new edit.

Comment: Can you show me *project.gradle*?

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez see new edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you have many dependencies, I thought this maybe related to [MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) problem which means your project has more than 64K methods. So you need to enable `MultiDex`  in order to have more than 64k

You can enable it by adding the following to the module-level `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

And then, create a `MultiDexApplication` class or extend from `MutliDexApplication` if you already have an application class.

Don't forget to add it to your `Manifest` :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Ok after updating the grandle and manifest, my classes can't find *"import com.example.myapp.R"*. How do I extend MultiDexApplication? Which classes extend it?

Comment: Try to `clean` and `rebuild` your project

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the correct dependencies for *app.gradle* are:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```

All services from firebase needs this dependencies, this one: *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'*, I think just adding the app indexing gms service and you need all package. Try with this changes and tell me about this, greetings!

Comment: Ok after adding that and changing to version 9.61. I get one error now. Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: This one is for multidex but your dependencies are correct now :)